# Go pkgsite show vulnerability error on page load

Tags: go, pkgsite

I am using pkgsite (commit: 2621a59a6537bf97015be7cc35b59aff6d414cb4) and hosted it on my private vm. I had pushed few go packages and those were getting rendered well. Recently, go pkg home page shown banner for vulnerability as:

```
: could not get vulnerability data: vulns("<pkg>", "<version>", "<pkg>"): GetByModule("<pkg>"): httpSource.GetByModule("<pkg>"): Index(): unexpected status code: 404
```

is there any recent change in pkgsite regarding vulncheck?